# css selector for table row in variable length table

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a table similar to this example

```
<tr class="line">...</tr>
<tr class="line">...</tr>
<tr class="line">...</tr>
<tr class="sum-line" id="i-know-this-one">...</tr>
<tr class="sum-line">...</tr>
<tr class="sum-line">...</tr>
```

With css (no jquery), how do I select the last `.line`? that is, the last `tr` before the `#i-know-this-one`.

Keep in mind that amount of rows before after `#i-know-this-one` will vary in my context, so we cannot simply count `nth-child` from top or bottom of the table

Comment: It is not possible by pure css.

Comment: You must to use javascript. With pure CSS you can't. Wait, you can if you change your html structure, but it's hardest than use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you use php or other language to output your table, then add a class or id to the last tr.line. And then apply styles to it.

Or use this, if it's applicable for your problem.

```css
tr:nth-last-child(3) {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="line"><td>...</td></tr>
  <tr class="line"><td>...</td></tr>
  <tr class="line"><td>...</td></tr>
  <tr class="sum-line" id="i-know-this-one"><td>...</td></tr>
  <tr class="sum-line"><td>...</td></tr>
  <tr class="sum-line"><td>...</td></tr>
</table>
```

Or another way:
Use tbody for .line and tfoot for .sum-line.
There will not be any problems then.

```css
   tbody tr:last-child {
      background-color: lime;
    }
```

```html
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="line"><td>...</td></tr>
        <tr class="line"><td>...</td></tr>
        <tr class="line"><td>...</td></tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr class="sum-line" id="i-know-this-one"><td>...</td></tr>
        <tr class="sum-line"><td>...</td></tr>
        <tr class="sum-line"><td>...</td></tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
```